# Usage and meaning of the question "when have you/I/we ever done...?"

Tags: grammar, american-english, present-perfect

Every grammar books that the of the question word *when* with the present perfect is a big no-no because it's totally incorrect. But in the sixth episode of the eighth season of *Friends* they actually used it that way. Here is the context:

> Joey: (entering) Hey!
>
> Monica: You didn’t dress up either?!
>
> Joey: Yes I did! I’m Chandler. (Looks at Chandler) Dude, what
> happened?
>
> Chandler: How is that me?
>
> Joey: Okay. I’m Chandler (makes a growling/gurgling sound at the end
> and the girls laugh.)
>
> Phoebe: (To Chandler) That is so you!
>
> Chandler: **When have I ever done that**?!
>
> Joey: **When have I ever done that**?! (And does the sound again.)

Here is [scene](https://youtu.be/4lcbcu75UU8). It's at 2 minutes and 16 seconds. What is Chandler trying to communicate by using the present perfect in an obviously incrrect way?

Comment: Does [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123053/using-when-with-present-perfect) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks! It really does

Answer (score -1):

I have labeled two sentences below:

> "When have I done that?!" (**sentence 1**)
> "When have I ***ever*** done that?!" (**sentence 2**)

One sentence uses the word "***ever***" The other sentence does not use the word "***ever***" .

sentence 2 is more grammatically correct (relatively speaking) than sentence 1.

the sentence without the word "***ever***" is more grammatically correct (relatively speaking) the sentence which uses the word "ever".

The sentence "**When have I ever done that?!**" is often used in American English.

Americans often do not follow the grammar rules seen in some grammar textbooks.

I was born in the United States and I am fluent in American English. I do not know what the phrase "***the present perfect tense***" means. Talking about things like "***the present perfect tense***" is a very difficult way to learn English.

I was taught English by people using simplified language. Also, I was given simple books to read. These short book contained short simple sentences and a small number of words. If you want to learn English, then I recommend reading books intended for children.

- I can recommend reading "the very hungry caterpillar" by [Eric Carle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_Carle).
- If you want to read more books then you can also read ["The Giving Tree"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giving_Tree) by Shel Silverstein. You are not required to read this book if you do not want to; these are suggestions.

I have met a lot of Americans in my life, and less than half of the Americans I have met have watched the television show titled, "***Friends***". I have watched the clip you provided a hyper-link to. However, I have never watched a full episode of the television show known as "***Friends***".

I have re-written the quote from the "***Friends***" television show. Some alternative passages of English text which mean something similar to the original are shown below:

Some passages of English text which mean something close to the quote "When have I ever done that?!" are shown below:

> - "I believe that I have never done that. Can you tell me about a time that I did such a thing?"
> - "Have I ever done that? If so, can you describe a time that I have done that?"

The word "***that***" has different meanings in different contexts.

In the context of the television show named "***Friends***", in the scene with the fictional character named "***Chandler***", we can translate the quote "When have I ***ever*** done that?!" as follows:

> - "I believe that I have never made a funny face and gurgling noise. Can you tell me about a time that I made a funny face and gurgling noise?"
> - "Have I ever made a funny face and gurgling noise? If so, can you describe a time that I have made a funny face and gurgling noise?"
> - "I have never made a funny face and gurgling noise. Prove me wrong."